# Semivariance of a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, variance

Semi variance is defined as : [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downside_risk), (see Examples).As per the formula semivariance of N(0,sigma^2) distribution comes out to be sigma^2/2

However Based on what I have been reading in my finance books semi variance for standard normals is same as variance.
So what is semivariance of a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just deal with the standard normal distribution.
Then, as I understand it, you are disregarding negative
data values and taking the variance of only positive values.

Intuitively, I anticipate the mean and variance of such
values to be the same as for the 'half-normal' distribution:
$\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $1 - 2/\pi,$ respectively. (Given
what we know about the related integrals of ordinary
standard normal distributions, I believe these values
are not difficult to prove.)

A simulation in R with a million standard normal samples, each of
size 100, gives the following results, verifying my guess (within 2 or 3
place accuracy):

```
m = 10^6;  sv = sm = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  x = rnorm(100); x.pos = x[x >= 0] # truncate to non-neg values only
  sv[i] = var(x.pos) 
  sm[i] = mean(x.pos) }
mean(sm);  mean(sv)
## 0.7977938  # aprx E(semivar)
## 0.3633463  # aprx V(semivar)
sqrt(2/pi); 1 - 2/pi
## 0.7978846
## 0.3633802
```

Here is a histogram of the simulated distribution of semivariances,
with a vertical red line at its mean.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @BruceET .. But what I am looking for, is getting the answer using the definition given in the link (which employs indicator variables)

Comment: And what I'm saying is that I don't believe the variance and semivariance of a standard normal distribution are the same. Maybe it's a misunderstanding: For a general normal, maybe the link denoted the variance as $\sigma^2$ and then gave a formula for the semivariance in terms of $\sigma^2,$ saying this is the same $\sigma^2$ as mentioned earlier. The use of statistical language in the link seems unclear and a bit sloppy to me. If you can explain the question without our having to slog through the link, maybe you will get the answer you are looking for.